# Cake Php 3.6 - ajax call sending empty data

Tags: ajax, cakephp, cakephp-3.0

In cake php 3.6 my ajax call is sending empty data to the controller.
I have included $this->loadComponent('RequestHandler'); in AppController.
Database does not save data and response is always an empty array.
Could not figure why this is happening.

**Ajax call:**

```
var clubeName = 'MyClub';
        $.ajax({
            method:'POST',
            async: true,
            cache: false,
            dataType: "json",
            url: '/Ajax/add',
            data: {'club' : clubeName},
            error: function(response){
                console.log('erro');
            },
            success: function(response)
            {
                console.log(response);
            }
        });
```

**My Controller action:**

```
public function add()
{
    $ajax = $this->Ajax->newEntity();
    if ($this->request->is('ajax')) {
        $ajax = $this->Ajax->patchEntity($ajax, $this->request->data());
        if ($this->Ajax->save($ajax)) {
            $this->Flash->success(__('The ajax has been saved.'));
            return $this->redirect(['action' => 'index']);
        }
        $this->Flash->error(__('The ajax could not be saved. Please, try again.'));
    }
    $this->set(compact('ajax'));
    $this->response->body(json_encode($ajax));
    return $this->response;
}
```

**EDIT**
**AJAX REQUEST PAYLOAD**

[image]

Comment: Flash doesn't work on ajax call..Also why are you redirecting it on ajax call?

Comment: removed flash and redirect and its the same. post is always empty and does not save in database named ajax

Comment: You can debug your ajax using Network tab of your browser.

Comment: Yes. i know. Debugging in network tab always empty array...

Comment: Did you check basics, like is `$this->request->is('ajax')` actually true? maybe you are sending the wrong headers?

Comment: The ajax payload is correct. Maybe the problem is in $this->request->data;

Comment: debugging $this->request->is('ajax')  returns true

Comment: debuging debug($this->request->data); says it is empty array []..... but the payload of the call has the correct data inside it

Comment: What exactly do the request details in your browsers network inspection tools look like?

Comment: The network tab shows status 200 and rhe request payload has the clubName value in it.

Comment: But in the controller dara is not arriving or arriving empty.

Comment: Please show what _exactly_ the request looks like, it's impossible to reproduce the problem with such little details.

Comment: Edited my answer to include request information screen.

Comment: As you can see the request payload as the clubeName in it "Porto", but the AjaxController add function is not seeing it. because debug to $this->request->data is always arriving empty array.

Comment: The payload is plain text, also indicated by the request content type. Either you're not showing the code that you're actually using, or there's additional code that is modifying your AJAX request.